# ugarchboot produces "EXPR must be a length 1 vector" error

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm following this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m6vH_1vMpc) but when I run the ugarchboot part I get the following error:

```
Error in switch(method, partial = .ub1p1(fitORspec, data = data, sampling = sampling,  : 
EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

Could someone tell me my error or how to fix this please?

I have installed the latest version of R (R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) and running on Windows.

```
install.packages("quantmod")
install.packages("rugarch")
library("quantmod")
library("rugarch")
fb-getSymbol("FB",auto.assign=F)
fbClose<-fb$FB.Close
fb1<-ugarchspec(variance.model = 
    list(model="sGARCH",garchOrder=c(0,0)),mean.model = 
    list(armaOrder=c(1,1)),distribution.model="std")
fbGarch<-ugarchfit(spec=fb1,data=fbClose,solver=c("hybrid"))
fbPredict<-ugarchboot(fbGarch,n.ahead=10,method=c("Partial","Full"))
```

It should just run successfully

Comment: There is something you missed in the video. It is actually used only the "Partial" method inside the video by indexing :  `c("Partial","Full")[1]`. You forgot to put `[1]`. Instead of this, you can just put the "Partial" inside the method  like : `fbPredict<-ugarchboot(fbGarch,n.ahead=10,method=c("Partial"))`

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd watch the video several times and missed it consistently. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

As @maydin said, I'd missed the [1] in the fbPredict command. The command should be:

```
fbPredict<-ugarchboot(fbGarch,n.ahead=10,method=c("Partial","Full")[1])
```

Thank you for your help